# Play framework 2 Constraints client side validation

Tags: playframework-2.3

I am currently using Play Framework and was wondering if there is a helper template out there (even by a 3rd party) that will add the HTML5 attributes (e.g. required) based on the model annotations.

For example on my model

```
public class MyModel {
   Constraints.Required(message="Required")
   public String name;
}
```

on my View.Scala.html

```
@helper.inputText(
            field = myModelForm("name"),
            '_label -> "Name",
            '_class -> "form-control",
            '_showConstraints -> false,
            '_showErrors -> true)
```

Is there an existing set of helper templates or 3rd party plugin that will add the required attribute on the HTML element?

I thought about creating my own helper templates but I'm not very familiar with Scala and do not know how to use reflection to check for attributes. If you are familiar with this syntax, please help! This would give me the flexibility to use Angular validation or jQuery validation but it's not a requirement at this point.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're asking for an automated constraint framework and only offer 50 rep...

Comment: @MartijnR Unfortunately, that's all I had at the moment. I've already started working on it so hopefully, I will share it on GitHub soon.

Comment: I don't think this is question worthy atm. Also, this shouldn't be too hard to implement, just add a switch case for all possible types of validation and make all the inputs accept an array of checks.

Comment: @MartijnR Yeah the question is asking whether anyone is aware of a plugin.. An alternative was to show the syntax of a scala template to create the attributes based on the constraint.... So if it's easy, why don't you post an answer and get your 50 points

Answer (score 4):

There is a module for this: https://github.com/loicdescotte/Play2-HTML5Tags

I just tested it occasionally but seems it does what you need (at least with most popular constraints like `Required` `MinLength` etc. Also allows to use input fields with `email` or `number` type.

If it won't satisfy you I'm pretty sure that you can use it as reference and create custom solution.